# How to get the last modified file in a directory using VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, file-search

Im looking for a way to do this in Excel 2010 using VBA.

It used to be possible in Excel 2003 using the Application.FileSearch method, but this has be depreciated. (see below)

```
Dim sFileName As String

sFileName = ""
With Application.FileSearch
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = sDir
    .Filename = "*.*"
    .Execute msoSortByLastModified, msoSortOrderDescending

    If .FoundFiles.Count > 0 Then sFileName = .FoundFiles(1)

End With
```

Any ideas how to do this in Excel 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using the FileSystemObject is acceptable, you could use the method described [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1626406&page=12).

To summarize:

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fol As Scripting.Folder
Dim fdr As Scripting.Folder
Dim fil As Scripting.File
Dim flc As Scripting.Folders

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("YourPathName")
Set flc = fol.SubFolders

For Each fdr In flc
  For Each fil In fdr.Files
        Debug.Print fil.DateLastModified
  Next fil
Next fdr

Set fso = Nothing
Set fol = Nothing
Set flc = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, works a treat. Just need to go through the list of file and maintain a variable with the file with the greatest DateLastModified.

Comment: As an aside, doing it this way also means that it works with all Excel 2003/2007/2010 (at the very least).

Comment: not work, his find not last modified but last looped