# Get file modification times and names

Tags: excel, directory, excel-2007, filetime

I have a directory that contains multiple files and want to get the modification times and file names from there for modification times between set dates.

I have tried `=FILEDATETIME` in Excel 2007 but it’s returning `#NAME?`, so I assume that function does not exist.

How is this possible?

Comment: Using VBA? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6427230/2258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a cheat as far as using Excel goes, but I find this easiest via command prompt (`cmd` in Programs). CD to required 'folder', then `dir >list`. Open file 'list' in Excel (ah, not quite totally irrelevant!) and parse with `=LEFT(A6,16)`in `B6` and `=MID(A6,37,200`*`)` in `C6`. Copy formulae down as required, then Sort or Filter by `ColumnB`,

*If you use ridiculously long file names, up the `200`.

There used to be a System command in 1-2-3 that did this for you (and I rather miss it).