# Open most recent .csv file in a folder

Tags: vba

I'm pretty new to VBA but I am trying to learn a lot more. Right now I'm trying to code a macro to open the most recent file in my :Z drive that is a comma delimited file (.CSV). The below code doesn't work but I was wondering if anyone had any advice? 
thanks for you help!

```
Sub NewestFile()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

MyPath = "Z:\"
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> “ \ ” Then MyPath = MyPath & “ \ ”
  MyFile = Dir(MyPath & “ * .csv”, vbNormal)
  If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox “No files were found…”, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
      LatestFile = MyFile
      LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
  Loop
  Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr Yes, the last modified file as long as it's a .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Version 1 I have simply used a msgbox to display the last modified csv in the folder. Version 2 opens the file and uses filedialog due to OP difficulties with file path from fso.GetFolder.

Add reference to [MS Scripting runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba) (tool > references ) then

```
Sub GetLastModifiedCSV()

   'Early binding code. Requires reference to MS Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject     
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

   'Late binding code. To be used instead of two lines above if "user-defined type not defined" /No reference added. You would uncomment line below.

  'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    Dim myFolder As Object

    Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test")

    Dim currentFile As Object
    Dim maxFileName As String
    Dim maxDate As Date

    For Each currentFile In myFolder.Files

        If fso.GetExtensionName(currentFile) = "csv" Then

            If currentFile.DateLastModified > maxDate Then
                 maxDate = currentFile.DateLastModified
                 maxFileName = currentFile.Name
            End If

        End If

    Next currentFile

   Msgbox maxFileName

End Sub
```

Additional references:

1) [How to get the last modified file in a directory using VBA in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427081/how-to-get-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-using-vba-in-excel-2010)

2) [Using VBA FileSystemObject, specific file File extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354947/using-vba-filesystemobject-specific-file-file-extension)

3) [File system object explained](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/)

4) [msoFileDialogFolderPicker](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/vba-select-folder-with-msoFileDialogFolderPicker/)

**Version 2 Using FileDialog to get folderpath for GetFolder:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetLastModifiedCSV()

    Const folderPath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test"

   'Early binding code. Requires reference to MS Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

   'Late binding code. To be used instead of two lines above if "user-defined type not defined" /No reference added. You would uncomment line below.

  'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("FileSystemObject")

    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim currentFile As Object
    Dim maxFileName As String
    Dim maxDate As Date

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If .Show Then
      Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))  ' & "\" 
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    End With

    For Each currentFile In myFolder.Files

        If fso.GetExtensionName(currentFile) = "csv" Then

            If currentFile.DateLastModified > maxDate Then
                 maxDate = currentFile.DateLastModified
                 maxFileName = currentFile.Name
            End If

        End If

    Next currentFile

    'MsgBox maxFileName

    Workbooks.Open fso.BuildPath(myFolder, maxFileName) 

End Sub
```

Comment: What does Compile error "user-defined type not defined" mean?

Comment: I'm still getting a path not found error when I run the code. I'm also not sure where I tell the code to pull the file from my Z: drive. I'm sorry for being slow, I'm still learning. Thank you for your time and help QHarr!

Comment: that's not a problem. so we have clered the initial error.  Now you should have replaced this  Const folderPath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test" with  Const folderPath As String = "yourfolderpath\yourfolder" to get to the folder containing the CSVs you are working with. Are you using a Windows machine btw as process is slightly different for mac. Don't be afraid to ask questions though tomorrow will now be the response timeframe.

Comment: Thanks. Take your time. I replaced "yourfolderpath\yourfolder" with "Z:/" At this point the code runs properly but the only thing that happens is an empty message box pops up.

Comment: No I'm using Windows on a PC. But I just copy the destination of my folder from the file explorer destination bar. and it gives me Z:\

Comment: You're right my b. At this point I don't get any errors. The macro runs and a blank msg box pops up but no files open.

Comment: No, I really appreciate all your time and help trying to figure this out. I'm using the latest version of windows and excel. Version two opens the Windows explorer where I select my Z drive to open. But none of the files show up in the drive. The msg box is still empty.

Comment: If I could attach screenshots I would... I feel like we are close to the solution but it's not recognizing .czv files when it looks for files to open.

Comment: The longer route is to use the Dir function to produce the files in a loop and check for csv. I am guessing it makes no difference if you put .csv? It should be csv though. Did you try the loop I suggested of  putting debug.print currentFile.Name    as a line above For Each currentFile In myFolder.Files ....and then looking in the immediate windows (Ctrl & G) to see if any files being processed by fso?

Comment: Cool okay so now the message box displays the name of the file that I want to open but it does not open. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does it now display? Have you changed something? I didn't add the code for open sorry as I was just getting you the file! Is it my code as written above that is currently working? If so, I will add the open code.

Comment: Hey sorry I was out sick yesterday and I have been playing catchup most of today. I added the open code and now when I try to run it says 'excel cannot find Z:\" Its in the same place as always tho so I don't know why excel cant find it.

Comment: Debugging highlights the Workbooks.Open code I just imported

Comment: Is this a shared network drive? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/db9d5bd8-2d30-432f-95cf-5c11bf95dd18/cant-open-word-or-excel-documents-on-mapped-network-drive-using-office-2013?forum=officeitpro

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: that is why my code, which is correct, is having problems for you! Mystery likely solved. This issue is discussed in the link i posted but may not be straightforward to resolve. Is this an issue you have an IT department that could look at? You could give them the link I mentioned?

Comment: It discussed two things in particular: Allowed Trusted Locations on my network is checked  and Deleting and remapping the drive.

Comment: My I.T. dept. doesn't know jack so I'm ditching the automatic selection portion of this macro and switching to a manual selection. Where once you run the macro, a popup prompts you to select the file manually. The entire process involves opening a document, preforming simple formatting changes to the data, then saving and renaming the file. I had hopped the create a macro that automated all of this but it doesn't look possible for the macro to select the correct file reliably.

Comment: Do you foresee any problems with the code saving the updated file in my shared Z drive? In other words, will the code allow me to save in a shared drive or will it sketch out because of the shared file.

Comment: it is difficult for me to say but it could be  related to this trusted location point. It might something you can do yourself same as with a drive re-map. If you run the code and select something from your desktop folder or local folder does it work fine?